# Twitter text message filtering rules

Tags: html, regex, twitter

I wonder if there are any rules to format twitter text message before send it? It looks like twitter removes some characters from a message and also replace HTML codes to symbols (e.g. `&lt;` to `<`)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but if that's the case then escaping `&` to `&amp;` should probably fix it.  So you'd have `&amp;lt;`

Comment: This is not the only case. I guess there are other case and characters that aren't supported and I want to show user how message going to look like before send it to server.